# Do bidirectional entities require both sides to add each other in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Do bidirectional entities (OneToMany, ManyToMany) require both sides to add each other to be saved correctly in Hibernate? From my experience, they ***are*** required. Just trying to confirm my understanding.

That is, for the entitles below, are the indicated lines required?

```
        Student student = new Student("Carl");
        Course course = new Course("Science");
        ReportCard reportCard = new ReportCard("A");

        student.getCourses().add(course);
        student.getReportCards().add(reportCard);

        reportCard.setStudent(student); // <-- Is this required?
        course.getStudents().add(student); // <-- Is this required?

        studentRepository.save(student);
```

Student.java

```
@Entity
public class Student { 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
    private List<ReportCard> reportCards = new ArrayList<ReportCard>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

ReportCard.java

```
@Entity
public class ReportCard {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Student student;

    @Column
    private String grade;
}
```

Course.java

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    public List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

EDIT: Replaced `@JoinColumn` with `@Column`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hibernate (ad other JPA implementations) cares about the owning side of the association. The owning side is the side which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute. So, in your example, `reportCard.setStudent(student);`is required, but `student.getReportCards().add(reportCard);` is not.

But in general, it's indeed best to set each side of the association correctly, to have a coherent graph of objects and simply avoid bugs in your code.

Note that annotating your String fields with JoinColumn is wrong. They're not join columns, but columns. So you should annotate them with `@Column`, although it's also useless if you don't specify any attribute of the annotation.

Comment: So here the owner in `ReportCard` in relation between `Student` and `ReportCard`?

Comment: Yes, `ReportCard.student` is the owner side, since it doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute. `Student.reportCards` is the inverse side, since it has the `mappedBy` attribute.

Comment: so means we are stuck to use ReportCard as owner because if we put mappedBy in ReportCard it will give mappedBy is undefined ManytoOne exception?

Comment: The many side of a bidirectional OneToMany association **must** be the owner side. For a ManyToMany, you choose.

Comment: Sorry but I dint get you .First you say `ReportCard.student is the owner side, since it doesn't have the mappedBy`(having ManyToOne) then you say `OneToMany association must be the owner side`  so means the above user mapping is wrong.

Comment: What I said is the *the many side* must be the owner. You association is *one student* has *many reportcards". So, the many side is ReportCard. And ReportCard is the the owner. The field of the association is `ReportCard.student`, which is the owner side. I see no contradiction.

Comment: @JBNizet In other words, the table who has the foreign key id column is the owner, correct?

Comment: No. A ManyToOne can be mapped with a join table, and a many-to-many is always mapped by a join table. The owner side is the side without the mappedBy. In a ManyToOne, it must be the many side.

Comment: @JBNizet When I tried this out, calling `reportCard.setStudent(student);` and not `student.getReportCards().add(reportCard);` doesn't work. I have a `ReportCardRepository` which is a Spring CrudRepository. Saving `ReportCard` without saving `Student` results in `Not-null property references a transient value`.

Comment: That's expected. But that's now what you asked. You asked is, for the association between two entities to be saved, both sides of the associations had to be set.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry but could you elaborate on what you mean? You said `reportCard.setStudent(student);` is sufficient. So with that set, how can I save both `Student` and `Report` properly?

Comment: reportCard.setStudent() is sufficient for the **association** between the two entities to be saved. That doesn't mean it's sufficient for the entities to be saved.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, you're right. After saving the both Student and Report, only reportCard.setStudent(student) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, it can be helpful to manage this in the setters. In `ReportCard.java`

```
public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
    student.setReportCard(this);
}
```

And in `Student.java`:

```
void setReportCard(ReportCard reportCard) {
    this.reportCard = reportCard;
}
```

So then using `reportCard.setStudent(student);` will set both sides for you.